# visualsearch and data from json file

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, backbone.js

Does anybody know how to do correctly use VisualSearch (based on backbone) ? Indeed I have        a jsp file which sends me back a json array with email and ID from a mysql BDD I just want to make them appear in the VisualSearch box I've installed in a second jsp page but I don't how to do and where in the VS javascript section : quite lost between facetsmatches,valuematches... if someone knew...he'd save my day ;-)
thanks in advance.

Comment: it is interesting me too... I will be glad to see working example